# I want to get command on oracle sql

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

The things I looking for some help with command on Oracle DB.

Right now I not near that database so I cannot try anything.

I will write down on paper your answers and I will try them and will let you know.

For now some info:

I using OLE connection to database by using c# OLE Connect which command I need to execute to get:

**primary key every table:**

I already got SQL for primary key but I don't know how to execute it to change the casting things

```
            "SELECT a.owner, a.TABLE_NAME, b.column_name
            FROM all_constraints a, all_cons_columns b
            WHERE a.constraint_type='P'
            AND a.constraint_name=b.constraint_name
            AND a.TABLE_NAME = 'CASTING'"
```

Edit: removed the If exist (i will get all tables and foreach table I will add drop table query)

But how it on oracle (for now I will keep it I will let you know tomorrow morning 9-11 hours from now I will update this topic)

How I check if some columns `is_identity` it mean it auto_increment

and when I found it how to check

```
           **"IDENT_SEED ,IDENT_INCR ,IDENT_CURRENT"**
```

Last thing:

how can I get info from every table, info like that :

```
column_name, data_type, is_nullable, character_maximum_length
```

Thank you in advance for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) 
from all_tables 
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME_IN_UPPERCASE';
```

returns 0 if table doesn't exist (or your user doesn't have any privileges on this table)

```
select column_name, data_type, nullable, data_length, data_scale, data_precision 
from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME_IN_UPPERCASE';
```

gives details about table columns

And there is not such a thing as identity column in Oracle which version is less than 12c. Are you using 12c?

Comment: i am not sure how i can know that, it noy my database it my friend database i am help him with his project and we wanna build backup to oracle database 
how i can know which version is it?

Comment: @Asaf Shazar SELECT version FROM V$INSTANCE under SYS user

Comment: i will check it as soon as i arrive there

Comment: last question for now how i get primary key for each table?
is my query will work???

Comment: thank you i will try it and update this topic tommorrow

Answer (score 2):

Thanks you guys 
The project work.
The versiob is 11.42 so there no auto incerment
And everthing work perfect
All column info work
Primary keys work

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not have any way to drop table using `if exists table` clause. As a best practice, just drop the table and ignore the error using

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE mytable';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
END;
```

If you want to be notified, then use,

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE mytable';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
```

Regarding the table details, query `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`.

And, `IDENTITY COLUMNS`are available with Oracle `12c`. Which version are you on?

Query, `select * from v$version` to know your database version.

Query `all_tab_identity_cols` for `IDENTITY COLUMNS` details.

```
SELECT table_name, 
       column_name,
       generation_type,
       identity_options
FROM   all_tab_identity_cols
WHERE  owner = 'TEST'
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

**EDIT** As requested by OP regarding `PRIMARY KEY` of a table.

In `all_constraints`, the column `constraint_type` will have value `P` for primary keys. So, in your query, put `where constraint_type = 'P'`

Your query seems to be fine. Just execute it.

Comment: i will try that as soon as i arrive my friend to check that out

Comment: last question for now how i get primary key for each table?
is my query will work???

Comment: In `all_constraints`, the column `constraint_type` will have value `P` for primary keys. So, in your query, put `where constraint_type = 'P'`